# Is there a way to create a self-expanding layer with max-width restriction that contains left aligned text

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6zdBE/)

HTML:

```
<div class="SummaryTable">

    <div class="AddressContainer">

        <div class="Address">
          <b>Ship To: </b>
            <ul>
                <li>John Smith</li>
                <li>45 Holland drv.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

            <div class="Address">
             <b>Bill To: </b>
                <ul>
                    <li>John Smith</li>
                    <li>P.O Box 456</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.SummaryTable
{
width: 650px;   
text-align:center;
}


.SummaryTable .AddressContainer
{
width:650px;
}

.SummaryTable .Address
{
width:323px;
background-color:Yellow;
float:left;
border: 1px solid black;
height:200px;
}

.Address ul
{
width:130px;
min-width:130px;
max-width: 280px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:Green;
text-align:left;
padding:0px;
}

.Address li
{
list-style-type: none;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6zdBE/)

- I want to keep the **green box\element (ul)** centred in the 323px wide/200px or Auto high (.Address) layer both horizontally and vertically.
- I have achieved horizontal centering of `<ul>` by setting `fixed width + margin:0px auto`, but addresses vary in length and I don't just want some fixed size box where one longer address would appear centred under (Ship To\Bill To) heading and another shorter one will look out of place since text is aligned to the left.
- I want to see the text in the `<li>` stretch to the `<ul>` green box up to the maximum-width setting (e.g 280px) and the green box, whatever its size will be to remain centered horizontally and vertically in the `.Address` layer and consequently under the `Ship To\Bill To` headings.
- Main reason for this is that shorter addresses would look offset to the left in a fixed width `ul` element and if I make the width small than a line break would ensue for longer address, spreading the first and last name and or address over two lines. Using centrally aligned text in the `ul` element
  -Of course solves this problem, but I need left aligned text.

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle for this? A fiddle sais more than a thousand words... (Oh, and try breaking up your question in a couple of paragraphs/list items - makes it a bit more pleasant to read)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ekuhav/edit#javascript,html,live)**

If I understood well your question

Here is the modified CSS:

```
.SummaryTable{
  width: 650px;   
  text-align:center;
}    
.AddressContainer{
  width:650px;
}   
.Address{
  width:323px;
  background-color:white;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:200px;
}
.address b{
    display:block;           /*should do the trick*/
}
.Address ul{
  display:inline-block;     /*should do the trick*/
  background-color:orange; 
  text-align:left;
  padding:0px; 
}
.Address li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

I removed some margin-reft/right:auto, widths, min-width, max width and formatted a bit your `.summaryTable` css 'appearances'. Than a bit of playing with `display` property have done the trick.

Here is a demo using jQuery : **[demo jsBin with jQ](http://jsbin.com/ekuhav/4/edit)**

Comment: Yep, that looks correct for the ul width auto-resizing. But I want the  (Ship to/Bill to) above the (ul) and not inline with it. Also ideally I want the (ul) in the middle\vertically too of the 200px high .Address layer.

Comment: I don't understand the part: `I want the Shitp to/Bill to above the (ul) and not inline with it` How you mean exactly?

Comment: When I copy pasted your css it was like so: "Ship to[Ul block])" on the same line. But I since moved the (ship to\Bill to) to its own div and made it clear both so it stays above the address containing (ul). Anyway I can vertically align the ul in the middle of the (.Address) layer without using fixed margins ?

Comment: Not the easy way. I'd suggest you to use Javascript in this case. I can show you an example using jQuery.

Comment: There's a way to do it if you don't need more than two/three `li` elements in pure CSS

Comment: I will need four (li) elements for the address. One would think setting margin-top and margin-bottom to auto should do the trick but if JS is the only way I would love to see an example of it.